# Is there any real world difference in the following two SQL statements (updates that result in no net change)

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

Say I have a table 1 million rows and lets say 50% on the particular column is null (so 500k NULL and 500k non NULL). And I want to set all the rows to NULL.

Assume no indexing to simplify the domain.

```
UPDATE 
    MyTable 
SET 
    MyColumn = NULL
```

or

```
UPDATE 
    MyTable 
SET 
    MyColumn = NULL 
WHERE 
    MyColumn IS NOT NULL
```

Logic dictates that the latter is more efficient. However won't the optimiser realise the first is the same as the second as the WHERE condition and the SET only reference MyColumn.

Comment: do you have any indexes on the column? Ideally we should be filtering on indexes as this changes the query from a table seek to a table scan.

Comment: @JayG - see question I'm assuming no indexes for this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optimizer works against SELECT statements.
The optimizer does not affect ***how*** a table is Updated.
When you ask SQL-Server to updated Every row, then it will **Update EVERY Row**.
It will also **take a lot longer** to do this because you're affecting every row; which I believe means it will affect your **transaction log** too.

Be VERY Careful NOT do this.
You will create **Exclusive Locks on EVERY Record** in the entire table when this happens.
Even if the data is not actually changing, SQL-Server will still update the record nonetheless.
This **Might Cause Deadlocks** on that table if another process tries to use it during that time.

I speak from experience where every night our main database table would lock up for 15 minutes while a process (someone else wrote) was updating the entire table... Twice.
This caused all the other queries to wait for it to complete (some would timeout).
**Not even a simple Select statement could be run against it while it was Updating.**

Comment: A non-update (same value to same value) will not (always) cause a log entry. As always, it depends. See for instance Paul White's blog for more information: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/08/11/the_2D00_impact_2D00_of_2D00_update_2D00_statements_2D00_that_2D00_don_2D00_t_2D00_change_2D00_data.aspx

Comment: Thank you @deroby .  That was a bit of a confusing read for my lower-level of expertise. :) I did mention that I "believed" it would affect the transaction log.  I think it's safe to say, that in most scenarios you should operate under the assumption it would.  In my case the 3rd-Party database we work in uses TimeStamp fields in ALL their tables, so no matter if the data changes or not during an Update, I "know" it will affect the timestamp, ergo that should affect our Log as well - every time.

Comment: Absolutely! Anyway, I simply wanted to point you to some extra detail because of the fact you used "believe"... The silly part is that I only now realise that Gordon's answer below already included the same link... I now feel kinda dumb =)

Answer (score 2):

The optimizer will not realize that the first is the same as the second.

You should use the second form.  The first form will log the changes to the records that are not actually changed under some circumstances (but perhaps not in this particular case).  [Here](http://web.archive.org/web/20180406220621/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/08/11/the_2D00_impact_2D00_of_2D00_update_2D00_statements_2D00_that_2D00_don_2D00_t_2D00_change_2D00_data.aspx) is a good reference on this subject.